# Trigger alarm every year on certain day and month

Tags: vb.net

i want to create some kind of a program that reminds me sometning on some date (blah blah)
for example

If IsDate(12 / 6 / 2014) Then

msgbox("today is your birthday")

endif

so is it possible to somehow write the code to do this every year without writting 10-20 lines of code.. (like this)

If IsDate(12 / 6 / 2015) Then

If IsDate(12 / 6 / 2016) Then

If IsDate(12 / 6 / 2017) Then

so, same day and month but different year :D

Answer (score 4):

`Date` has properties on it for the current day and the current month.  You could compare the `.Day` and `.Month` properties of your "alarm date" and the current date to see if it should trigger.

The documentation on MSDN has a lot more information.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example:

```
    Dim alarmDate As Date = #3/11/2010#
    Dim currentDate As Date = Date.Now
    If alarmDate.Day = currentDate.Day AndAlso alarmDate.Month = currentDate.Month Then
        'Do Something here
    End If
```

You could also take this whole thing to the next level using extension methods (this is probably beyond your current application needs):

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module ExtensionMethods
    <Extension>
    Public Function IsSameMonthAndDayAs(d1 As Date, d2 As Date) As Boolean
        Return d1.Day = d2.Day AndAlso d1.Month = d2.Month
    End Function
End Module
```

Example:

```
    Dim d As Date = #1/11/2010#
    If Date.Now.IsSameMonthAndDayAs(d) Then
        'Do something here
    End If
```

**Even More**

If you want to turn this in to a functional application you could make a new form, drop a `Timer` component on to it, and set it's interval to 86400000 (number of milliseconds in one day).  Enable the timer and place my code in to it's `Tick` event.  The timer will fire once per day and compare the 2 dates.
**NOTE** this is NOT the best (or even a very good) way of doing this.  It's just an example of how to use it.

Comment: yeah but i think this will only trigger the program once.. i need it to be triggered every year on same day and month.

Comment: The `If` block will return true on any 2 dates that have matching days and months.  It's up to you to put it in to a timer or some other process that will repeat.

Comment: I've added some more information about one possible way to use the code.  Please let me know if it isn't clear enough.